# JNI/JNA vs Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String)?

Tags: java, shell, java-native-interface, runtime, jna

To my knowledge, anything that I can do in a command shell, I can do from JNI, JNA or `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String)`. So which to use when?

Is it that JNI/JNA allow me to communicate (interprocess communication, etc.) with a **running** native application that otherwise couldn't be performed from a command shell? Or is it just that `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String)` is platform-independent, whereas JNI/JNA require you to know the platform your on in order to use them?

Comment: Don't use `.exec` since like ..about 2005.  More broadly:  Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell,

- JNI and JNA permit using native *libraries* in the same process.
- `Runtime.exec` (and it's newer friend `ProcessBuilder`) launch new external applications.

Since each requires cooperation with the host operating system and an existing native binary (whether it's a library or a runnable program) none of them is platform-indepedent.

None of the three permits communicating with a **running** external application. To do that you need an [inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) mechanism, which can be implemented on top of shared memory, files, pipes, or sockets for example.